# Exporting wsdl of a SOAP service with Soap-Ui , in one single wsdl - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, wsdl, soapui

I have the following problem.
I'm using Eclipse IDE with Java code, then When i try to export my Soap service from Soap-UI program, i have two generated wsdl files, while instead i would expect just one.

I can see that inside one of the wsdl, ther's an import that calls the other part of wsdl .

my question is :

1 - is it possible to put all togheter the two wsdl in one single file wsdl ?

2- Is it possible to modify the project in order to create a one single wsdl file ?

i have another soap -services -based project, and when i export the wsdl ther's only one single file.

So i don't understand in which part of the project happens the split and fdon't know following which rules .

Comment: What is the difference between the two ? Is one http and one https ?

Comment: Seems to be that they are both Http  , the only thing that i saw it right now, it's that comparing the content with the editor , in one of the wsdl file we have the xsd part (which think it could be related to the modules , so to the output ). 
Maybe it depends from the framework, cause in my project i'm using CXF framework ? 
really i don't have the idea. With other project (without) cxf framework i don't have splitted wsdl. Just one single wsdl with more xsd files for every module/output present in the project